# Dialing down SOAPUI API logging

Tags: java, log4j, soapui

I am using the [SOAPUI API](http://www.soapui.org/developers-corner/integrating-with-soapui.html) to write integration tests for my SOAP Web Service.

My code is very similar to the sample code below:

```
// create new project
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();

// import amazon wsdl
WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl( "http://www.mycorp.com/somewsdl.wsdl", true )[0];

// get desired operation
WsdlOperation operation = (WsdlOperation) iface.getOperationByName( "MyOperation" );

// create a new empty request for that operation
WsdlRequest request = operation.addNewRequest( "My request" );

// generate the request content from the schema
request.setRequestContent( operation.createRequest( true ) );

// submit the request
WsdlSubmit submit = (WsdlSubmit) request.submit( new WsdlSubmitContext(), false );

// wait for the response
Response response = submit.getResponse();

//  print the response
String content = response.getContentAsString();
System.out.println( content );
assertNotNull( content );
assertTrue( content.indexOf( "404 Not Found" ) > 0 );
```

After I run this test it spews out a whole lot of log to the console. Is there a way one can dial down the SOAPUI logs.

I have the relevant SOAP UI code and its various dependencies in jar files .If this project is using common logging frameworks (I see a log4j jar in the dependencies) is there a way to programatically set the logging level ?

Some thing like

```
project.setLoggingLevel("INFO");
```

Comment: I'm sure you have already seen this, but have you tried modifying `%SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\soapui-log4j.xml`?

Comment: Like I said , I have the soapui code in a jar file. I don't have access to log4j.xml. I was wondering if the API can let me do that. In the WsdlProject java doc , there is a Logger defined but its a protected member.

Comment: How about this: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this.  You have to create two log4j configuration files because soapUI uses Apache httpclient which also uses log4j.  httpclient uses the default log4j.xml loaded as a classpath resource.

soapUI will try to load a log4j configuration file called "soapui-log4j.xml" as a classpath resource (happens in DefaultSoapUICore class).

You say in your message you can't change the log4j.xml in the jar, so you'll have to override it by placing the new ones first in the classpath so they are found first.

Here is my log4j.xml to keep httpclient logging low:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender name="console-apache" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS} [%t][%-5p] [%c] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.apache">
    <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>
<root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="console-apache" />
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

and here is my log4j-soapui.xml:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender name="console-soapui" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS} [%t][%-5p] [%c] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.eviware">
    <level value="INFO" />
</logger>
<root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="console-soapui" />
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Lastly, you can override any default loading behavior by defining a couple system properties defining where the config files are:

```
-Dsoapui.log4j.config=${yourpath}/log4j-soapui.xml
-Dlog4j.xml=${yourpath}/log4j.xml
```